# What is the difference between `{}` and `Map.of()`?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, constructor, named-constructor

I'm checking `Map` class. I would like to know the difference between these two below.

Are they exactly the same? What does `Map.of` do?

```dart
Map<int, int> m1 = Map.of({1: 1, 2: 2});
Map<int, int> m2 = <int, int>{1: 1, 2: 2};
```

Comment: `{}` creates a `Map` literal.  [`Map.of`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/Map.of.html) copies an existing `Map`.

Answer (score -1):

check the this [Dart docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Map/Map.of.html)

`Map.of()` is the same as `Map` init

- `Map.of()`

```dart
factory Map.of(Map<K, V> other) = LinkedHashMap<K, V>.of;
```

But my guess is that since `Map` initialization is a **variable assignment** and `Map.of()` is a **function call**, the movement of the assembly is that Map assignment will be faster.